# My android studio layout manager lost fuction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My android studio layout manager only has these two options, I don’t know what went wrong... I tried deleting the SDK and clearing the cache, but it still can’t return to normal...[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi9Af.png).Usually it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdOVh.png) . But when I create a new project, it is normally Show its toolbar

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple blank project with hello world and seeing if that works?

Comment: yes,it is works on new project , but it is not work on old one... @ThomasMorris

Comment: Ok, so that means something is wrong with your old project giving you a few options. You can try fix your old one or copy the code across to a new project(time consuming). If you have a backup use the git or zip or something. You can attempt to do a clean and rebuild as well.

Comment: Oh god, if I rebuild the project it will be a big project...

Comment: So I am trying to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components of that specific dropdown and all the icons next to it highly depend on which widget (ConstraintLayout, TextView, ImageView, etc.) is selected in the Code section (where your text cursor actually is in the file).

If the root container (most of the time a ViewGroup) is selected you'll see:

[image]

If any other widget is selected inside that ViewGroup (container) you'll get what you're after:

[image]

And worth mentioning that you will be shown something different (but relevant) when the selected widget is not inside a ConstraintLayout but some other ViewGroup:

[image]